# How to hide an image after one second

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation

I want to hide an image after one second, as a flip animation ends. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to hide after loading from viewDidLoad, Declare following in your viewDidLoad;

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(hideYourImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)hideYourImage
{
    [yourImageView setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

Here you are. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing flip animation using UIView animation, then you can specify code for animation completion.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2

 animations:^{// Put your flip animation}

 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [imageView removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Else, the timer method will also do.